# BeautifulSoup, How can i pull out all instances not in tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I really didn't want to write but i am stuck! 
How can i extract from this page all instances of just this part:

```
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html">
49,90 &euro;
```

I tried this one but the name and price aren't in that tag.

```
 wishlist = soup.find_all(class_="tooltip")
```

Many many thanks in advance

```
<tr onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor = '#E1EAFE'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'">
<td class="tooltip" id="21010" width="180">
<div class="wishlist-img-frame">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html">
<img class="wishlist-img" src="thumb_Azul.jpg" alt="Azul" title="Azul" id="img_Azul" data-pagespeed-url-hash="2469707013" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
</div>
<br>
<small><a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html">Azul</a> </small>
</td>
<td class="">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html">2-4</a>
</td>
<td class="" width="60">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" title="Tedesco
" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3016993694" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
</td>
<td class="" width="60">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" title="Italiano
" data-pagespeed-url-hash="2763445148" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" title="Tedesco
" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3016993694" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
</td>
<td class="">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html"><img src="https://www.uplay.it/stock_1_1.png" alt="Disponibilità: Immediata (poche copie)" title="Disponibilità: Immediata (poche copie)" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3301201864" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
</td>
<td class="">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html">
49,90 &euro;
</a>
</td>
<td style="">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" data-nome="Azul" style="margin-right:5px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="update_cart('21010');" id="Azul" class="basket" data-pagespeed-url-hash="2966354299" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="0" class=" wishlist-row--border" colspan="10" < tr>
<tr onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor = '#E1EAFE'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'">
<td class="tooltip" id="2264" width="180">
<div class="wishlist-img-frame">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html">
<img class="wishlist-img" src="thumb_Balloon_Cup.jpg" alt="Balloon Cup" title="Balloon Cup" id="img_Balloon_Cup" data-pagespeed-url-hash="536172911" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
</div>
<br>
<small><a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html">Balloon Cup</a> </small>
</td>
<td class="">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html">2</a>
</td>
<td class="" width="60">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" title="Inglese
" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3505320999" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
</td>
<td class="" width="60">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" title="Inglese
" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3505320999" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" title="Italiano Scaricabile Online
" data-pagespeed-url-hash="2558428881" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
</td>
<td class="">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html"><img src="https://www.uplay.it/stock_7.png" alt="Disponibilità: Prodotto Fuori Catalogo O In Fase Di Ristampa" title="Disponibilità: Prodotto Fuori Catalogo O In Fase Di Ristampa" data-pagespeed-url-hash="2464760904" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)"/></a>
</td>
<td class="">
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html">
17,80 &euro;
</a>
</td>
<td style="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

'''

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
The best one would be:

https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html
49,9
https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html
17,80

but i can edit and split the whole string
"<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html">
49,90 &euro;"
<a href="https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html">
17,80 &euro;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
play = """your html above"""

for a in soup.select('td> a[href]'):
    target = a.text.strip()
    if len(target)>0 and '€' in target:
        print(a['href'],a.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Azul.html 49,90 €
https://www.uplay.it/gioco-da-tavolo-Balloon-Cup.html 17,80 €
```

Edit:
To write to a csv file for importation to Excel try:

```
with open('play.csv', mode='w') as play_file:
    play_writer = csv.writer(play_file, delimiter=',')    
    for a in soup.select('td> a[href]'):
        entry = []
        target = a.text.strip()
        if len(target)>0 and '€' in target:                
            entry.extend([a['href'],a.text.strip()])
            play_writer.writerow(entry)
```

Comment: great man, thank you a lot! I don't want to bother you, but can you give me an hint of how to separate the two elements? So i can save an excel in two columns! I'll try by myself too in the meantime!
Thanks again a lot

Comment: ok i did it, more or less, i have to polish.
But if you ever want to put down a few lines i'll be glad to study your style, since i tried for two days to accomplish what you did in a few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks again. I alredy did it this way and seems to work.
Now i have to polish the cells value!

```
wishlist = []

for a in soup.select('td> a[href]'):
    target = a.text.strip()
    titolo = target

    if len(target)>0 and '€' in target:
        #print(a['href'],a.text.strip())
        price = a['href'],a.text.strip()
        wishlist.append([price, titolo])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=wishlist, columns=['Titolo', 'Prezzo'])    
df.to_excel(r'wishlist.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```